# Changing an integer in Java

Tags: java, int, immutability

I Know that in Java, Integer is an immutable object. but I need a way to be able to change an integer in a method and see the change outside the method.
For example:

```
int getInt(){
    int my_int=0;
    test(my_int);
}

void test(int i){
    i=3;
}
```

What I want to see as the output of `getInt` is `3` not `0`.
Is there any way to do that?

my method is more complicated than what I wrote, and it will return another object. That's why I want to change the int in the input and not return it.

Comment: may be this will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/3981536

Comment: Another option to those given already: You could have a member variable within the class instead of a local variable in the method. This one could be accessed from anywhere necessary and you do not have to bother with passing it around.

I admit, this somehow spoils the rest of the class, so I would rather prefer an alternative - *unless* there is no such rest, as the only purpose of the class is doing the calculation (and it is possibly even discarded afterwards). Then I would consider this a valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't. You need to wrap it into a container object which is able to change its content. Eg:

```
class IntWrapper {
  private int value;
  ..
}
```

Or you can return a new value and assign the result to it, eg

```
int x = 10;
x = foo(x);
```

which is basically equivalent to your example.

Comment: Thanks my method is more complicated than what I wrote, and it will return another object. That's why I want to change the int in the input.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible if the argument has to be an `int` primitive. You *can* use an `AtomicReference<Integer>`

```
AtomicReference<Integer> iRef = new AtomicReference<>(0);
test(iRef);

void test(AtomicReference<Integer> ref) {
  ref.set(3);
}
```

This is honestly kind of an anti-pattern - it's often not super clear from looking at the method signature what's going to happen to your values. It'd be clearer to have `test` return an int, and then have something like `i = test(i);`.